# P-Values alternative when the sample is large

Tags: p-value, sample-size, effect-size

It is a well known fact that the P-Value can be made as small as one likes, by increasing the sample size. In the big data era, it is outdated, and there is no much sense in using hypothesis testing with only one possible outcome: "reject the null hypothesis".

I wanted to ask for your opinion on this matter, and more specifically, how do you analyze the data then ?

Graphically, I find it more sensible to use standard deviations rather then standard errors. In addition, calculation of effect size is a must. Is there anything else one can do ? Assuming that I wish to run a linear regression, or a t-test, and my sample is huge, which approach should be taken ?

Thank you !

Comment: How you analyze the data depends on what you want to do with it!  If it makes sense to test a hypothesis, *then it makes sense no matter how much data you have.*  What you seem to be saying, then, is that using hypothesis testing as a default form of analysis is what makes no sense--and I doubt anyone would disagree with that.  But that leaves us hanging, because in that light your question comes down to "how do I analyze a lot of data"?  That's too vague and general to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

In linear regression the R squared measurement tells you if the overall model is able to explain a relevant amount of the overall variance. As long as R^2 is small, factors with tiny p-values are not of particular benefit.

A t-test can be regarded as a regression with one categorical predictor, so the story is the same.

Also, a (Pearson) correlation of 0.15 could be regarded as small even if significant (p<0.00001).

Another possibility can be to go with Bayesian approaches.

Comment: Thank you, can you expand a bit further on the Bayesian approach ?

Comment: @user3275222 - I am no expert in Bayesian Analysis, but what you get from e.g. a Bayesian Linear Regression is instead of a point estimate per parameter, a posterior distribution. That means you can way better evaluate the possible range of plausible values for your parameters of interest. The wider the distribution, the more uncertainty. 

What remains crucial to Bayesian analysis is the decision of the prior distribution. A nice and basic introduction to the topic is e.g. 
[Article on Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-bayesian-linear-regression-e66e60791ea7).

Comment: Cheers, very helpful

Comment: It sounds like this answer is advocating looking at *effect size statistics* (r-squared, Pearson r, Cohens's d is not mentioned but might be used with t-test, and so on).  I agree that this may be helpful.